# Question: Why nexus blob store structure is different from s3 structure?

Tags: amazon-s3, nexus

I am using Nexus repository with AWS S3.
Here is my build.gradle file.

```
respositories {
    maven {
        url "<My Nexus Proxy Repository URL>"
    }

}
```

And the type of repo is S3.

when building gradle, successfully finished building gradle.
But, the structure of the blob store of the nexus repo is different from the aws s3.

nexus repo is like:

```
ch/
com/
io/
jakarta/
ognl/
org/
```

s3 is like:

```
content/vol1
content/vol2
...
content/vol30
```

Why they have different file systems? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blob store is an internal binary storage system designed to handle components from all sorts of different ecosystems, including ones that don't map particularly well to a directory structure. What were you hoping to do by accessing S3 directly?

Comment: Thanks. That's just my curiosity.
Then, if I need to remove or edit files, then do it through Nexus, not aws s3 ??

Comment: That's correct. The S3 storage, like the embedded database, is an internal data store not intended for you to modify directly. Any deletion or re-publications, definitely do that through Nexus UI, your package manager CLI talking to Nexus, or via Nexus REST endpoints.